# "Rectangularity" measure of a polygon

Tags: geometry, reference-request

For an arbitrary polygon, I want to be able to calculate how "rectangular" it is.

Does any work exist which has tried to do this?

I found [An Efficiently Computable Metric for Comparing Polygonal Shapes (Arkin et al., 1991)](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~dph/papers/ACHKM-TPAMI-91.pdf), which develops a metric for comparing arbitrary polygons. So one way to do what I want might be to use this metric and compare the polygon to some rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it could be to determine the [minimum bounding rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) of the given polygon, then use the "coverage factor" (ratio between the area of the polygon and area of its bounding rectangle) as a measure of similarity. This will be a percentage varying from $0\%$ for a thin star-shaped polygon to $100\%$ for an actual rectangle. For convex polygons, the lower bound is $50\%$ (e.g. triangles) as discussed in [Area ratio of a minimum bounding rectangle of a convex polygon](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93521/area-ratio-of-a-minimum-bounding-rectangle-of-a-convex-polygon) on MO. Some links to relevant algorithms can be found at [Finding minimum-area-rectangle for given points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/finding-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points).